# data being stripped off after ampersand in URL even when using urlencode

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, urlencode

I am passing ampersands in a URL which go into a get request

e.g.

```
http://www.soundshelter.co.uk/label/Hit & Run
```

I have tried to urlencode the & so that it is a valid URL

```
http://www.soundshelter.co.uk/label/Hit%20%26%20Run
```

but the `& Run` section of the URL is being cut off in the get request.

I'm thinking this might have something to do with my mod_rewrite

```
RewriteRule ^label/([^/]*)$ /index.php?label=$1 [NC]
```

the get request is

```
$label = $_GET['label'];
```

Any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: http://www.soundshelter.co.uk/label/<EVIL CODE>

Answer (score 3):

From [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

> 'B' (escape backreferences)
>
> Apache has to unescape URLs before mapping them, so backreferences will
>   be unescaped at the time they are
>   applied. Using the B flag,
>   non-alphanumeric characters in
>   backreferences will be escaped. For
>   example, consider the rule:
>
> ```
>  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?show=$1
> ```
>
> This will map `/C++` to `index.php?show=/C++`. But it will also
>   map `/C%2b%2b` to `index.php?show=/C++`,
>   because the `%2b` has been unescaped.
>   With the `B` flag, it will instead map
>   to `index.php?show=/C%2b%2b`.
>
> This escaping is particularly necessary in a proxy situation, when
>   the backend may break if presented
>   with an unescaped URL.

So, try:

```
RewriteRule ^label/([^/]*)$ /index.php?label=$1 [BNC]
```

---

Also, having gone to your page, it looks to me like you have further PHP problems. I suggest you post more code context.

Comment: Hi mate, thanks for that. That is bringing up an Internal Server Error. Any ideas? Also what part of the code would you need to see for the further php problems? Cheers for your help

Comment: (a) Look at your server error log. (b) Make a testcase: a minimal, complete page of code that _only_ exhibits the problems, but also does not contain irrelevant bumpf that doesn't contribute to it.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your rewrite rule to

```
RewriteRule ^label/([^/]*)$ /index.php?label=$0 [NC]
```