# PHP - urlencoded() ampersand in url perceived as actual ampersand

Tags: php, parameter-passing, urlencode, ternary-operator

There is an dummy example PHP application which shows what causes me problems.

```
<?PHP
echo ((isset($_GET['P'])) ? print_r($_GET) : "<a href='http://example.com/a.php?P=" . urlencode('One & Two') . "'>One & Two</a>");

?>
```

If we visit page without P parameter page will output: 
http://example.com/One+%26+Two

And that's fine, but if we visit the link, script will return:

```
Array

    (
        [P] => One
        [Two] => 
    )
```

And that's obviously WRONG. 
In real application, in url is submitted about 30 char long alphanumeric string which contains special letters(Swedish).

Edit: In my real application I use URL rewrite:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ../example.php?s=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Can that be the cause? - Confirmed. It was the issue. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send your URL using the `%` to escape the ampersand.
Try it like this `'One %26 Two'`

```
<?PHP
echo ((isset($_GET['P'])) ? print_r($_GET) : "<a href='http://example.com/a.php?P=One %26 Two'>One & Two</a>");
?>
```

Comment: So I should escape ampersand which will be escaped by urlencode? Did you even read complete question?
Thanks anyway.

Comment: You never said you were using rewrite either. You wouldnt need to use urlencode if you escaped it with %

Comment: This is huge project, and url rewrite is added two months ago, when project is started, so I completely forgot about it. 
In real application, it's much more things in URL to encode than in example, so encoding each manually is not an option.

Comment: You only gave **this** example of your problem. You never said you had many urls or that this was a problem in the entire application. We are not mind readers. :)

Comment: But I did, in beginning I said that is dummy example application, and somewhere near end I said: "In real application..."

Comment: As you tried to help, but you wasn't been able to because I forgot important thing to mention, I accepts your answer as solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can follow this.if your array is like that

```
$data = array('p'=>'one',
          'q'=>'two');
```

you can build url like this

```
echo http_build_query($data)
```

it will give output like this

```
p=one&q=two
```

Comment: Thank's for reply, but how exactly your answer fixes my problem?

Comment: first make an array using key and value.then make that array to url using http_build_query().

Comment: And? You just told me way to build url query, something I already know, but didn't used in example for simplicity sake. The problem is not with url encoding but PHP-s way it sees URL encoded string.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Problem was laying out of PHP powers.

It was problem with URL rewrite:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ../example.php?s=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

The new working version:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ../example.php?s=$1 [B,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Reference: [data being stripped off after ampersand in URL even when using urlencode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316795/data-being-stripped-off-after-ampersand-in-url-even-when-using-urlencode?rq=1)

Comment: The `B` flag properly escapes the URL so & becomes `%26` which is what I said to do manually. However your rewrite rules were not a part of your original question. So yes I did read it.

Comment: But doing manually is not the solution as in real application, it's a lot more things to encode.

Comment: I understand, if the given the rewrite rules originally a proper answer may have been give. Good luck with your app.